# webservice with JSON

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I am trying to make an application that gets JSON data from a web service and puts it in a listview but this is not working. It's not crashing or giving error messages. the web service is not giving me any data.

this is my code :   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
ListView listview;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
String[] data;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    listview = findViewById(R.id.listview);

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build());

    MPWebservice();

    listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, bestelling.class);
            intent.putExtra("naam", listview.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}



private void MPWebservice() {
    String Webadres = null;
    String dbResult = "empty";
    dbConnect database = new dbConnect(this);

    try{
        String query = "SELECT * FROM adres";
        Webadres = "?query=" + URLEncoder.encode(query, "UTF-8");
        String con = "https://amje.000webhostapp.com/mariosPizzaJSON.php" + Webadres;
        dbResult = database.execute(con).get();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
        JSONArray ja = new JSONArray(dbResult);
        JSONObject jo = null;
        data = new String[ja.length()];
        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++){
            jo = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            data[i] = jo.getString("Naam");

        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.layout_list, R.id.list_item, data);
        listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

This is the JSON data from the web service :

```
orders: [
{
naam: "J. Hecker",
adres: "St Rochusstraat 40",
postcode: "5611 RJ",
bestelling: [
          {
            Pizza: "Siciliane"
          },
          {
            Pizza: "4-Stagione"
          },
          {
            Pizza: "Hawaii"
          },
          {
            Pizza: "Siciliane"
          }
        ]
},
```

Here is the Logcat :

```
05-30 11:22:26.415 11361-11361/com.example.stefan.mad_oefenexamen W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: Value {"orders":[{"naam":"P. Melissen","adres":"Grote Berg 101","postcode":"5611 KJ","bestelling":[{"Pizza":"Hawaii"},{"Pizza":"Siciliane"},{"Pizza":"Napolitane"},{"Pizza":"Margarita"},{"Pizza":"Margarita"}]},{"naam":"M.  Dijk","adres":"Jan Smitzlaan 2","postcode":"5611 LE","bestelling":[{"Pizza":"Margarita"}]},{"naam":"Th.M. Neessen","adres":"Hoefkestraat 31","postcode":"5611 RM","bestelling":[{"Pizza":"Napolitane"}]},{"naam":"T. Bazelmans","adres":"Hertog Hendrik van Brabantplein 29","postcode":"5611 PG","bestelling":[{"Pizza":"4-Stagione"},{"Pizza":"Hawaii"},{"Pizza":"Siciliane"},{"Pizza":"Margarita"},{"Pizza":"Salami"},{"Pizza":"4-Stagione"}]},{"naam":"L. Cals","adres":"Geldropseweg 5","postcode":"5611 SB","bestelling":[{"Pizza":"Margarita"},{"Pizza":"Napolitane"}]}]} of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

Comment: follow this tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Remember, in your manifest file you must give internet permissions `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`

Comment: @Mimmetico i did that, but its still not giving data.

Comment: you are ignorring the exception. That is why you don't see the reason why the code does not work. Never leave catch block empty

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko still nothing :(

Comment: I don't see any changes in code.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko i added the code in the catch block.

Comment: Ummm... try to cast the ListView: `listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);`

Comment: @Mimmetico im 100% sure that its not a code problem, since i used the same code in a different project, and that did work. its a webservice problem. could it be that the table name in the database, and the arrayname in the json are different?

Comment: so there are no any stacktraces in the logcat after you added that `e.printStackTrace()`?

Comment: It's possible. In your Json you wrote "naam" and in your code your wrote "Naam". For android are differents. Try to change.

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko I found a useful error in the logcat. I added the line above. Its says it can not be converted to an array. maybe this is the problem?

Comment: yes, it is a problem. Your response from the server is a JSONObject, not a JSONArray

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko How can i fix this problem?

Comment: good start would be to find a tutorial about how to parse JSON

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienkoI did that. but it is not working in my case. Can you please help me?

Comment: have you tried to change this line: `data[i] = jo.getString("Naam");` for this one: `data[i] = jo.getString("naam");` ?

Comment: Same question asked as this; i replied here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602165/json-parsing-to-listview-arrayadapter/50602923?noredirect=1#comment88215266_50602923

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the response from server is JSONObject not JSONArray. And this JSONObject contains JSONArray of the following

```
{
naam: "J. Hecker",
adres: "St Rochusstraat 40",
postcode: "5611 RJ",
bestelling: [
      {
        Pizza: "Siciliane"
      },
      {
        Pizza: "4-Stagione"
      },
      {
        Pizza: "Hawaii"
      },
      {
        Pizza: "Siciliane"
      }
    ]
    },
```

To get these values do like this, assuming your JSONObject response is jsonResponseObject

```
try{
 JSONArray jsonArray=jsonResponseObject.getJSONArray("orders");
 for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length(),i++){
 JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
 Log.d("Naam",jsonObject.getString("naam"));
 }catch(Exception e){
    e.printstacktrace();
 }

}
```